# Spring security Java config custom AuthenticationProvider order

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

Using the following code to configure Spring security, I can see in ProviderManager, List AuthenticationProvider has two elements.

MyAuthenticationProvider at index 0 and AnonymousAuthenticationProvider at index 1.

My question is that is there a way to make AnonymousAuthenticationProvider at index 0?

```
public class MyWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

I can do http.anonymous().disable() and init and set AnonymousAuthenticationProvider manually but

1. I am not sure what key for constructor I need to provide.
2. it is more like a workaround.

Comment: Why do you want to place AnonymousAuthenticationProvider at index 0?

Comment: because i want the "lastException" (cant' remember the field name but something like that.) to be the one from my custom provider.